# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl

I setup a json method to parse the returned data but I keep getting the error
`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):`

```
def get_json(url)
      encoded_url = URI.encode(url)
      uri = URI(encoded_url)
      result = Net::HTTP.get(uri) # => String
      @json = Crack::XML.parse(result).deep_symbolize_keys
    end
```

I'm also requiring the following:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/https'
require 'crack' # for xml and json
require 'crack/json' # for just json
require 'crack/xml' # for just xml
```